# как сделать цикл из классов

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    $('.price-out-a1').click(function(){
    $('.price-out-cont_1').slideToggle(500);       
    });
```

Как правильно написать цикл для увеличения цифр (обоих, которые идут и после `а` и после `_`) с шагом 1 до 33(включительно). Чтоб получалось .price-out-a2/a3...a33 и соответственно cont_2/cont_3...cont_33 
Блин знаю нубский вопрос, но что-то никак не дается мне...

Comment: похоже на костыли

Comment: обьясните детальней что вам нужно сделать и какая у вас разметка

Answer (score 0):

Можно задать только один класс... и при клике на него - просто определить номер кликнутой кнопки и по этому же номеру "отслайдить" нужный класс )) [если уж они идут строго парами]

```
$('.price-out-a').on('click', function(){
  /* Это дело ниже определяет номер кликнутой кнопки, среди классов .price-out-a */
  var x = $(this).index('.price-out-a');

  /* По этому же номеру и тыкается на ...cont, с помощью .eq()*/
  $('.price-out-cont').eq(x).slideToggle(500);       
  /* После каждого клика, 'x' становится конкретным числом */
});
```

Если вообще без вариантов, сильно хочется именно по-вашему записать, это будет выглядеть так:

```
for(var i = 1; i < 34; i++){
  $('.price-out-a' + i ).click(function(){
    $('.price-out-cont_' + i ).slideToggle(500);       
  });
}
```